# Confused with python codehs 8.4.4

Tags: python

So I'm trying to slice out the middle names that the user entered and print them but it isn't working and I don't know what do do.

I've already tried looking it up

```
name_amount = int(input("How many names do you have? "))
namelist = []
index = 0
for i in range (name_amount):
    name = input("Name: ")
    namelist.append(name)
    index += 1
print "You have " + str (name_amount) + " names."
print "Middle names: " + namelist[0][1:index - 1]
```

For example, if you say you have 3 names and say L then T then K I want it to say

`Middle names: T`

but instead it just says:

`Middle names:`

and then nothing else.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `namelist[0][1:index - 1]`? Shouldn't the middle name just be the second element in namelist? Moreover, before you print a middle name, shouldn't you check that the user has at least 3 names entered?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
name_amount = int(input("How many names do you have? "))
namelist = []
index = 0
for i in range (name_amount):
    name = input("Name: ")
    namelist.append(name)
    index += 1
print "You have " + str (name_amount) + " names."
try:
    print "Middle names: " + namelist[1]
except:
    print "No middle names found"
```

Change:

```
print "Middle names: " + namelist[0][1:index - 1]
```

To:

```
try:
    print "Middle names: " + namelist[1]
except:
    print "No middle names found"
```

And that's it, It will work...

Comment: Thank you but like with the other answer it has to work with any amount of names

Answer (score 0):

You should change to return the second element in the list and also add a sanity check that finds if more than two names are entered in the first place.

```
name_amount = int(input("How many names do you have? "))
namelist = []
index = 0
for i in range (name_amount):
    name = input("Name: ")
    namelist.append(name)
    index += 1
print "You have " + str (name_amount) + " names."

# Checking if at least 2 names are entered
if name_amount > 2:
    print "Middle names: " + namelist[1]
else: 
    print "Could not find a middle name"
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work because it has to work if there are more than 3 games as well not just 3.

Comment: So if i enter "A B C D", is the middle name "B C"?

Comment: And what is the expected behaviour when less than 3 names are entered?